# How to create these scrolling effects?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you give me an idea how to create the scrolling effect of this website:
http://eee.asus.com/eeepad/transformer-prime/features/

Is this created using javascript, HTML5 and CSS3? How?

I'm reading the view source right now.

Thanks

Comment: Excellent example of a site with way too many bells and whistles getting int eh way of actual usability. :)

Comment: Holy... just how creepy is that?

Comment: Have to agree with @Scott. I don't expect my websites to look like car commercials :\

Comment: well maybe that is their theme and idea. To have effects while scrolling the page.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to use a plugin like [Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/) to achieve these parallax effects.